# XPath text() expression - what to specify in text() if it contains newline

Tags: xpath

The text is as:

> text1
> text2

How can I specify this text in xpath. I tried:

```
.//*[@id='someid']//h6[text() ='text1text2]

.//*[@id='someid']//h6[text() ='text1\ntext2]

.//*[@id='someid']//h6[text() ='text1 text2]
```

None of them worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the working code

```
   .//*[@id='someid']//h6[. = 'text1text2']
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `normalize-space()` to remove the line feed and compare text without this issue.

```
//*[@id='someid']//h6[normalize-space(text()) ='text1 text2']
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.//*[@id='someid']//h6[. = 'text1&#10;text2']`. This assumes you are writing the path inside of XSLT or XForms where you can use `&#10;` to escape a new line character. If you are not using XSLT you might want to tell us in which host language (e.g. PHP, C#, Java) you use XPath.

Comment: I am using java and selenium...I have to specify this xpath in By.xpath expression

Comment: .//*[@id='someid']//h6[. = 'text1text2'] is working..Thanks a lott :)

Answer (score 2):

not very elegant but it works

```
.//*[@id='someid']//h6[contains(text(), 'text1') and contains(text(), 'text2')]
```